# Is it faster to use selectors with the context parameter?

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors, selector

Is it faster to use selectors with the context parameter instead of specifying it?

Examples:

```
var source = $('option:selected', 'select#source').text();
```

**vs.**

```
var source = $('select#source option:selected').text();
```

Which is faster, and why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The context parameter is mainly of benefit if it's a cached value, not a selector:

```
var source = $('select#source');
var selected = $('option:selected', source);
var nonselected = $('option:not(:selected)', source);
```